# Laravel - Check if an event is colliding with other event

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an "employee_pauses" table which contains pauses durig the shifts of the employees. Each row has a start_date and end_date col which are datetimes.

When I make an appointment I select the range of the new event and then send the requests to the controller where I get them. I have to check if there is a "pause" between the appointments start and end time.

It should look like this:

---

employee_pauses.start_date= 2018-10-03 08:00:00

employee_pauses.end_date= 2018-10-03 08:30:00

---

$request->get('app_start_time') = 2018-10-03 07:00:00

$request->get('app_end_time') = 2018-10-03 10:00:00

---

I should have a returned collection with 1 row that there is a pause between the two requested times.

I tried this query. What am I doing wrong?

```
$pauses = EmployeePause::whereRaw("((start_date < ? AND end_date > ?) OR (start_date < ? AND end_date > ?))", [$start_time, $start_time, $end_time, $end_time])
                ->where('employee_id', $request->get('employee_id'))->get();
```

My "employee_pauses" table looks like this:

id - int(10) primary_key

employee_id - int(11)

start_date - datetime

end_date - datetime

Comment: provide your `employee_pause` table structure

Comment: added it into the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `Employee Pauses` where `request start_date and end_date` is between `employee_pause start_date and end_date`

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
$start_date = $request->app_start_time;
$end_date = $request->app_end_time;
$employee_id = $request->employee_id;

EmployeePause::where('id', $employee_id)
    ->whereBetween('start_date', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->whereBetween('end_date', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think i made a mistake, I updated the answer, please check

Comment: yes, I updated it, working fine, thank you very much!